# How to set border and rotate a bitmap image in Android?

Tags: android, image

I am an absolute newbie to android.
I have a bitmap that I fetch from an URL. I want to show it in the middle of an image view that is at the top of my screen. I also want a border around the image. Currently when I rotate with the following code it just go to the top:

```
private static void imageWithBorders(ImageView im, View image){
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
im.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.setRotate((float) -20f);
im.setImageMatrix(matrix);
im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

When I set like this the image is not at the center, Also how to set border around it?

I am expecting something like this.

[image]

Any possible ways to achieve this is appreciable. Please help me with this.!

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#10171C"
android:gravity="center" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:rotation="10"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

create a xml file in your drawable shadow_gray.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

it will not showing rotation in graphic layout in xml. but when it will run then it will showing like this.

[image]

Comment: The problem is there is no borders in this image.

Comment: @Kannan_SJD please check my answer again. it covered your solutions also.

Comment: Thanks..!! I m checking it

Comment: Welcome @Kannan_SJD If my ans helped you then please mark as right for others.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
android:rotation="20"// 20 is the angle
```

give this code to ImageView

And to border please put the ImageView in LinearLayout

and give this code to within ImageView tag

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

and if you want border color then just do this

give a color to the LinearLayout background by this

```
android:background="#ffffff"//#ffffff is the color code
```

Answer (score 1):

`Matrix mymatrix = new Matrix();`

`imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);`

`mymatrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);`

`imageView.setImageMatrix(mymatrix);`

this will rotate your image view

set padding=1px and set Background color to linearlayout , THen you'll have a 1px  border.
If you want further clarifications inform me

Answer (score 0):

If you put the padding=5 and the background color in the Imageview, you'll have a 5px white border and take main layout as Linear layout and set background image on that to achive this.

```
android:rotation="20"// 20 is the angle



      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="5dp" >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:Background="@drawable/test1"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


        </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But here you have given src, I am not going to set the image with setImageBitmap, is that ok??

Comment: now check my code i have updated for your requirement.

Comment: But i am fetching it from the URL and then setting it programatically.. Anyway let me try this

Comment: it's working on dynamically  same just you have to set padding and background color dynamically..